# Can I duplicate a pivot table column without it combining data with another column?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a set of data with 3 categories (small subset of data shown in first image).  Each row is a response from a partner organization (data hidden in additional columns).  They respond to each Q with a value of 0-4.

[image: example data from excel]

I'm trying to create a pivot table to summarize results.  I'd like the frequency of responses to each question to be shown in a set of columns.

Here is a single set of responses in a pivot table  This is good, except I'd like to duplicate the last 6 columns for Q2 and Q3 in the same pivot table.

[image: Pivot Table example with a single set of responses]

I can add the Q2 and Q3 response columns to my Values box, but it doesn't produce the right information (having checked a few cells).  It looks correct, but when I manually check the data, some are not showing the correct value.  I suspect it has to do with the `Response to Q1 (0-4)` field that is in the Column area in the pivot table option.  If I remove it, I lose the 0,1,2,3,4 column options.

[image: pivot table with added q2 and q3 responses]

Ultimately, what I would like to accomplish is to have a set of columns with the frequency of response (0-4) to Q1, then a set of columns with the frequency of response (0-4) to Q2 etc.

Comment: This looks like Excel, is that what you are using or is it something else?

Comment: Yes, I will add that tag.